# Equivalent To Test-connection from powershell, on VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, powershell, connection, ping

I have this code:

```
If (Test-Connection $Computer -Quiet) {
    If ($Computer -eq 'localhost') { #Checks to see if system is localhost and gets its actual Computer name.
        $Computer = ls env:Computername
        $Computer = $Computer.Value
    }
```

And actually there was a really good way to see if the server responded and return a boolean if it did or didn't, which is "Test-Connection $Computer -Quiet"

Is there some simple solution to this for VB.NET?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [`System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx).

Comment: I Actually used My.Computer.Network.Ping(Computer), is it the same?

Comment: @FerMelon: No idea (I don't do VB, so don't know the mapping of `My` to underlying types) but could well be the same thing (or at least an equivalent).

Comment: @FerMelon Yes that appears to be the same, but generally you want to handle the reply too...